# can i make a tkinter window and image be transparent

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to have a transparent window that can show an image with transparent background I have searched a lot but found  actually useful I have tried a ton of solutions in other questions but all of them display the image with a different colored background I want true transparency

**Edit:**
heres the closest i got to what i want but theres still a weird yellow outline on the image i used aswell as a white outline:

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import ImageTk

root = Tk()

root.geometry("400x400")


root.config(bg = '#add123')
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill='both')

canvas = Canvas(frame, bg='#add123')
canvas.pack(fill='both')

photoimage = ImageTk.PhotoImage(file="gnomef.png")
canvas.create_image(200, 200, image=photoimage)


root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor','#add123')
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [mre], and read about [ask]. Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: If you got some transparency, but has some outline showing up, it is because the color in your image is close to the color that is trated as transparent, but not the exact color.  See: the pixels have to be exactly `#add123` to be transparent. Just open your image in an image editing software, such as GIMP, and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

It is the *highlight border* of the canvas which can be set to zero using `highlightthickness=0` of `Canvas(...)`:

```py
canvas = Canvas(frame, bg='#add123', highlightthickness=0)
```

Actually you can simply use a label instead of frame and canvas:

```py
import tkinter as tk

trans_color = "#abc123"

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry("400x400")
root.wm_attributes('-transparentcolor', trans_color)

photoimage = tk.PhotoImage(file="gnomef.png")
tk.Label(root, image=photoimage, bg=trans_color).pack(fill="both", expand=1)

root.mainloop()
```